# Denied check-in tfs-online when some time has passed

Tags: tfs

I am normally able to check-in tfs online.

But if a certain amount of time (say 30 minutes, I am not sure of the exact no of minutes passed) has passed since I loaded the solution or checked in last, then I am denied check-in.

If I then reload the solution from tfs online, I am allowed to check-in.

The denied check-in situation occurs often and is extremely annoying. Is there any way I can avoid a denied check-in situation without having to reload the solution ?

Comment: This happens to us every day.  We thought it had to do with the connectivity between the developer machines and the data center location with the TFS server.  We thought it had to do with a hiccup in the connection at which point the connection had to be recalled.  We just attempt to do the check-in or get latest or save of the Work Item changes again and it usually resolves it.  Very occasionally we have to close and re-open the client interface.  I would be very interested in hearing a solution if our presumption is incorrect.

Comment: Did you receive any error messages when the system refused to check in? Can you share the message here for troubleshooting?